# In emacs eshell auto-completion, how to return function instead of file name?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have a file named: "mytest.bat", when I type:

```
myt (tab)
```

The autocomplete return me the whole file name "mytest.bat", instead of "mytest" as a function.

How can I get the function name "mytest" instead of the file name in eshell autocompletion?

Answer (score 0):

From seeenter code hereing a `batch` file in your question. Assuming now, you're on windows, this seems to be a normal behavior to me. Windows adds a convenience layer while in `cmd` which let's you write `mytest` instead of `mytest.bat`. There is an environment variable to customize this behavior. I can't remember it's name anymore, though. Maybe somebody else can shed some light on this as I can't reproduce anymore as I'm using Linux for years now. Anyway, if you've ever seen Mono (aka .NET for Linux / Mac OS) programs run on either Linux or Mac OS from console then you noticed that you most likely stated the whole file name `foo.exe`. This is what you now see in emacs happening. And you can do just this in emacs shell:

```
alias mytest mytest.bat
```

See: [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Aliases.html).